# How to add manual error bars on specific geom_points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

Hello I recently asked a question about adding additional specific data points to a ggplot that were not included in a data set. Now I am trying to add error bars to those data points but nothing I do seems to work. This is what I have so far:

```
 dat1 <- data.frame(x = "-/-", y = 2837.3333, Well = "0", errors = 334.02993877795)
 dat2 <- data.frame(x = "+/+", y = 1911.33333, Well = "0", errors = 103.568010)
 dat3 <- data.frame(x = "-/-", y = 137, Well = "8", errors = 158.745)
 dat4 <- data.frame(x = "+/+", y = 259.6667, Well = "8", errors = 197.616630)
 dat5 <- data.frame(x = "-/-", y = 95.666, Well = "16", errors = 93.0931)
 dat6 <- data.frame(x = "+/+", y = 557.6667, Well = "16", errors = 133.82949)
 dat7 <- data.frame(x = "-/-", y = 74.333, Well = "32", errors = 66.515)
 dat8 <- data.frame(x = "+/+", y = 757.3333, Well = "32", errors = 43.98106)

 ggplot(well_data4, aes(x = E2F4, y = Colonies, color = Clone, fill = E2F4)) +
 geom_point(aes(color = Clone), size = 2) +
 geom_point(data = dat1, aes(x=x, y=y), color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2)+
  geom_errorbar(data = dat1, mapping = aes(x = x, ymin = y - errors, ymax = y + errors), width  = 0.2, color = "black")+
geom_point(data = dat2, aes(x=x, y=y), color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2)+
geom_point(data = dat3, aes(x=x, y=y), color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2)+
geom_point(data = dat4, aes(x=x, y=y), color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2)+
geom_point(data = dat5, aes(x=x, y=y), color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2)+
geom_point(data = dat6, aes(x=x, y=y), color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2)+
geom_point(data = dat7, aes(x=x, y=y), color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2)+
geom_point(data = dat8, aes(x=x, y=y), color = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2)+
```

all the different geom_points show up perfectly fine, but when I try to add geom_errorbar to one specific it says my aesthetics don't match up. I think it is trying to match it to my original data set well_data4 which is what my graph is made up of, but is there anyway to get it to just pertain to the new data set I made dat1 ? I would like to add them to all of them, hopefully to look like the picture I attached. Thanks so much.

[desired graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biICM.png)

Here's some of the data (i think??)

```
structure(list(E2F4 = c("+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/- 
", "+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "+/+", "+/+", "+/+", 
"-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-"), Colonies = c(430, 43, 306, 
17, 317, 77, 504, 710, 459, 16, 198, 73, 808, 735, 729, 7, 140, 
76, 2864, 2769), Clone = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "2", 
"7", "11", "Control", "Control", "Control", "2", "7", "11", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "2", "7", "11", "2", "2"), Well 
= structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "8", "16", "32"), 
class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: (1) it is far better to use single frames, differentiated by clear categorical data, than to use 8+ frames; (2) `object 'well_data4' not found`, unable to reproduce.

Comment: As was requested in your previous question, please post at least a sample of your data by pasting the output from `dput(well_data4[1:20, c("E2F4","Colonies","Clone")])` (just the columns we need, and "enough" rows to support most of the `Well`-frames you provided at the top of your question).

Comment: Okay I just posted. Sorry I wasn't sure how to do that before. Is that correct? Also, do you know the best way to put all the data together but still have it run the same way?

Comment: Yes, that is a great to post data, thanks!

Comment: FYI, you have newlines in `E2F4` in well `"8"` (as `"-/-"` and `"-/- \n"`), I suspect that's a mistake.

Comment: I'll be honest I can't find where that is but yes its def a mistake thank you

Comment: Perhaps you put it in while pasting ... notice on the first line, you have `"-/-` and then the next line starts with its closing quote `"`. I'm fixing it in my answer, likely not in your real data.

Comment: Oh yes I see so sorry was a pasting error!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a few things to help here:

1. combine all of the `dat#` frames into a single frame, it makes the code much easier to work with (imo) and therefore easier to maintain
2. rename `x` and `y` in it so that the aesthetics match those set in the initial call to `ggplot` (`E2F4` and `Colonies`, respectively)

Also, two assumptions:

- I'll assume that the `errors` number should be added to and subtracted from the `Colonies` count; and
- there is one `E2F4` that has a newline in your sample data, likely a paste-error, I'll clean it up.

Further, I don't know how you got the x-axis the way you did there, I'll add facets and some theming to get it close to your pic.

```r
well_data4 <- structure(list(E2F4 = c("+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-"), Colonies = c(430, 43, 306, 17, 317, 77, 504, 710, 459, 16, 198, 73, 808, 735, 729, 7, 140, 76, 2864, 2769), Clone = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "2", "7", "11", "Control", "Control", "Control", "2", "7", "11", "Control", "Control", "Control", "2", "7", "11", "2", "2"), Well = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("0", "8", "16", "32"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# combine all dat# into a single frame
library(dplyr) # other ways exist if you don't want to use dplyr
datX <- bind_rows(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4, dat5, dat6, dat7, dat8) %>%
  rename(E2F4 = x, Colonies = y) %>%
  mutate(
    ymin = Colonies - errors,
    ymax = Colonies + errors,
    Well = factor(Well, levels = levels(well_data4$Well))
  )


ggplot(well_data4, aes(x = E2F4, y = Colonies, color = Clone, fill = E2F4)) +
  facet_grid(~ Well, switch = "both") +
  geom_point(aes(color = Clone), size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(x = E2F4, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
    data = datX, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "HT29 Colony Survival", x = "Concentration of SN-38 (nM)") +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(), # normally they are gray bg, this removes gray
    strip.placement = "outside",        # normally b/w axis labels and ata, this shifts below
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt")       # normally clearly framed/spaced, this makes it look like one canvas
  )
```

[image: ggplot with error bars]

Comment: Wow this is incredible thank you so much. I did all of this but when I run it I get : Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'ymin' not found. I'm so confused because it ran the mutate function fine?

Comment: It's in there. I just broke out the `mutate` code a little to make it clear that it's there and what is needed to be added. If it persists, make sure that the `ymin=` _in the `geom_point(..)` expression_ is inside of the `aes(..)` block.

Comment: I figured it out!!! thank you so so much I couldn't have done this out without your help